# Как передать токен в запросе к API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch

Требуется получить данные от сервера по API
На моменте авторизации мне возвращается токен, который сейчас сохранен в localstorage.
Как его передать в GET запрос для получения данных ?

```js
<template>
    <div class="lk">
        <h2>Личный кабинет сотрудника</h2>
        {{posts}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {mapState} from "vuex";

    export default{
    name: 'lk',
    data(){
        return{
            'posts': [] 
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        let lk = await fetch('http://10.1.5.65/api/personal/users/');
        let posts = await lk.json();
        this.posts = posts
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
        user: state => state.user
        })
    }
}
    </script>


import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
})

export default store
```

Comment: Я если честно, совсем не понимаю при чём тут теги `vue` и `vuex`.  Вы `fetch` или `axios` используете?

Comment: Надо смотреть документацию на используемый API. У каждого API свои требования по передаче токенов. Часто это делается в заголовке Authorization: barier .... но могут быть и другие заголовки, вроде Token: или например через куки и даже через параметры запроса

Comment: @Mike `bearer`.

Comment: @doox911 использую fetch

Comment: @Mike передать токен нужно в заголовке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Необходимо получить токен из `localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
async mounted() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') // Или ваш ключ хранения токена
},
```

2. [Передаём его в `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```js
async mounted() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') // Или ваш ключ хранения токена

  if () {
    await fetch('http://10.1.5.65/api/personal/users/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,  
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Что-то если вдруг нет токена
  }
},
```

Так же доп. [материал](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).